# Qt Application Deployment error: the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b

Tags: qt, qml

I am on windows 10 using qt creator 4.8.2 and i am having errors in deploying my application. The errors states that (the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b) even though i have installed all the needed DLL files. I have been trying to use dependency walker and Qt 5.9.8 (MSVC 2013 64-bit) for the file input. I am in need of help thank you.

Dependency walker and Qt 5.9.8 (MSVC 2013 64-bit)

(the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b)

Comment: Are you sure the bit-ness is correct everywhere? Which program gives the error, is it the actual application or maybe the deployment tool?

Comment: I am using a x86 and i am trying to deploy the .exe file which is created after the program's release. Thank you.

Comment: The error pops up when trying launching the exe file.

Comment: You can run 32bit applications on a 64bit system, however, not the other way around. Attempting to start a 64bit application on a 32bit (like your x86) system will result in said error.

Comment: My qt application is based on a [Qt Creator 4.8.2 based on Qt 5.9.8 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit] so does this mean the project i created is in 32bit thus i should run the application on a MSVC 32-bit in order to have my DLLs. Thank you.